# Tracking stock prices using Python and Google Sheets

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, finance, google-sheets

The purpose of this program is to keep track of some stocks that we bought in a game and every week we must list the closing prices of each stock in a Google Sheet. I thought since I had a lot of different investments to keep track of I would write a quick script to do it for me. And I could have my friends in class send me their stocks as well to save them time.

I am just looking for any bad practices I might have in my code as well as any more efficient ways of carrying out some of the functions.

```
from yahoofinancials import YahooFinancials
import re
import pygsheets
import pandas as pd
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()
time_now = (now.year, now.month, now.day)
time_now = str(time_now)

data = []
formatedData = []
shortData = []
everything = []
tickers = ['XOM', 'JNJ', 'TR', 'CRON', 'HSY', 'FL', 'PLNT', 'MCD', 'ARLP', 'LULU', 'RCII', 'DELL', 'DNKN', 'DIS']


def main(sheet, everything,place):
    gc = pygsheets.authorize(service_file='creds.json')

    # Create empty dataframe
    df = pd.DataFrame()

    # Create a column
    df['Closings: ' + time_now] = everything
    # open the google spreadsheet (where 'PY to Gsheet Test' is the name of my sheet)
    sh = gc.open('PY to Gsheet Test')

    # select the first sheet
    wks = sh[sheet]

    # update the first sheet with df, starting at cell A2.
    wks.set_dataframe(df, (1, place))  # up/down,left right


for i in tickers:
    tick = YahooFinancials(i)
    history = tick.get_historical_price_data('2019-03-07', '2019-03-08', 'daily')
    y = str(history)
    data.append(y)

for i in data:
    i = i[i.index('adjclose'):]
    i = re.findall("\d+\.-?\d*", i)
    i = str(i)
    if len(i) > 7:
        formatedData.append(i[2:9]) #the decimals were really long so this shortens them down a bit
    else:
        formatedData.append(i)

y = 0
for i in tickers:
    x = i
    x = x + " : " + formatedData[y]
    y = y + 1
    everything.append(x)


def get_name(person):
    if person == 'tommy':
        sheet = 0
    elif person == 'chad':
        sheet = 1
    elif person == 'kaya':
        sheet = 2
    elif person == 'twohey':
        sheet = 3
    elif person == 'majers':
        sheet = 4
    elif person == 'tori':
        sheet = 5
    elif person == 'kayla':
        sheet = 6
    place = input("What Week Is This? 1,2,3,4,5?: ") # This will move the entry one place over for each week
    place = int(place)
    main(sheet, everything,place)


print('DONT FORGET TO CHANGE TICKER')
person = input("Whos Data Is Going In: ")
get_name(person)
```

Answer (score 2):

This looks very interesting. Well done!

---

Here is some nitpicking:

> ```
> from yahoofinancials import YahooFinancials
> import re
> import pygsheets
> import pandas as pd
> import datetime
> ```

- Organise these imports in following way: builtins, third-party then first-party.

> ```
>  def main(sheet, everything,place):
> ```

- Name of this function is sloppy. Use `main` function as an entry-point.
- Name the function as a verb phrase or that explains what it is doing.
- What is `everything` here? I can see that it is defined outside as well.
- Avoid using `everything` as a name. It is very vague.

> ```
> for i in tickers:
>     tick = YahooFinancials(i)
> ```

- What is `i` here? Reserve `i` for integer indexes. These are ticker_names.
- `for ticker_name in tickers` is more readable.

> ```
> tickers = ['XOM', 'JNJ', 'TR', 'CRON', 'HSY', 'FL', 'PLNT', 'MCD', 'ARLP', 'LULU', 'RCII', 'DELL', 'DNKN', 'DIS']
> ```

- Load this from a JSON file.

> ```
> def get_name(person):
> ```

- This function doesn't **get** you anything. There is no return.
- Why does this call `main`?
- Name to sheet mapping can probably be loaded from a JSON as well.

> ```
> adjclose, PY to Gsheet Test
> ```

- Perform extract constant refactoring on strings like these and remove magic values.

> A magic number is a direct usage of a number in the code.
>
> For example, if you have (in Java):
>
> ```java
> public class Foo {
>     public void setPassword(String password) {
>          // don't do this
>          if (password.length() > 7) {
>               throw new InvalidArgumentException("password");
>          }
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> This should be refactored to:
>
> ```java
> public class Foo {
>     public static final int MAX_PASSWORD_SIZE = 7;
>
>     public void setPassword(String password) {
>          if (password.length() > MAX_PASSWORD_SIZE) {
>               throw new InvalidArgumentException("password");
>          }
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> From: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47882/what-is-a-magic-number-and-why-is-it-bad

---

- **Summary** - This code is very hard to understand. Functions do things that are completely different from function-name. Variable names are vague. Contains lot of hard-coded values that can be extracted to a JSON or some other kind of config. Contains magic values that should be converted to meaningful constants.